# Toggle Class b/w Two Buttons Using Angular

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I would like to apply the bootstrap styling of the btn-success class upon click and change the class of the other button to btn-warning.

However when I run it the bootstrap styling does not change anything.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

http://plnkr.co/edit/9xV6hRA929sFRDCDBEpy

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-snapshot/angular2.js" data-semver="2.0.0"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="true col-xs-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block" ng-class="{true: 'btn-success', false: 'btn-warning'}[!yupNope.isSelected]" ng-click="!yupNope.isSelected ? (yupNope.isSelected = !yupNope.isSelected) : ''">True</button>
    </div>
    <div class="false col-xs-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block" ng-class="{true: 'btn-warning', false: 'yupNope'}[!yupNope.isSelected]" ng-click="!yupNope.isSelected ? (yupNope.isSelected = !yupNope.isSelected) : ''">False</button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `ng-class` object backwards. It should be `{'class-name': boolean}` Also you need to have the boolean value varaiblized so that it can be changed and it not just a hard-coded `true`/`false`

Change the first button to

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block" ng-class="{'btn-success': yupNope.isSelected, 'btn-warning': !yupNope.isSelected}" ng-click="!yupNope.isSelected ? (yupNope.isSelected = !yupNope.isSelected) : ''">True</button>
```

The difference is in ng-class:

```
ng-class="{'btn-success': yupNope.isSelected, 'btn-warning': !yupNope.isSelected}"
```

Also, your `ng-click` for both buttons are the same, which would only do something if `yupNope.isSelected` is falsy.

Comment: I appreciate the input. However I have edited my plnkr to reflect your changes and it still does not work

Comment: Are you sure you edited it to reflect the changes? `{'btn-success': yupNope.isSelected, 'btn-warning': !yupNope.isSelected}[yupNope.isSelected]` != `{'btn-success': yupNope.isSelected, 'btn-warning': !yupNope.isSelected}`

Comment: Also, your plunker is broke. It has errors in the console. Try this one: http://plnkr.co/edit/45HCJQhUAHw2F1IuXqFT?p=preview (The script is script.js, not app.js)

Comment: Perhaps I am not implementing your changes appropriately. I have edited my plunkr to reflect them. No more console errors but not the desired functionality. Again thank you for the help.

Comment: @RyeGuy You are correct, you are not implementing the changes appropriately. Look very hard at your `ng-class` vs what I am suggesting. You will see `[yupNope.isSelected]` in your code, now DELETE it. Also, there are more errors in your code because you have changed more things. "testViewer" !== "plunker" (The name of your module does not match the value of `ng-app` anymore, they should match)

Comment: I appreciate the effort. Its now doing something. Going to rethink the ng-click to make sure one is warning and the other is default